# Python Fabric: How to answer to keyboard input?

Tags: python, automation, fabric

I would like to automate the response for some question prompted by some programs, like mysql  prompting for a password, or apt asking for a 'yes' or ... when I want to rebuild my haystack index with a ./manage.py rebuild_index.

For MySQL, I can use the --password= switch, and I'm sure that apt has a 'quiet' like option. But how can I pass the response to other programs ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why can't you just use [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)?

For example, for an automated auto accept, just use [`yes`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29), that just outputs a neverending stream of `y`.

```
yes | rm *.txt
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f6/Pipeline.svg/280px-Pipeline.svg.png))</sub>

Comment: What if the command *sometimes* prompts and sometimes does not?  How can I pipe yes only when I know there will be a prompt?

Comment: and what if i have a complex command, asking 2-3 times yes/no and numerical value after ?

Answer (score 39):

If you are looking for a user to confirm an operation, use the confrim method.

```
if fabric.contrib.console.confirm("You tests failed do you want to continue?"):
  #continue processing
```

Or if you are looking for a way to get input from the user, use the prompt method.

```
password = fabric.operations.prompt("What is your password?")
```

Comment: Instead of using Fabric's prompt for a password, I would recommend importing getpass and using that so that you don't display the password on the terminal as it's being typed. For non-password input, then I agree that Fabric's prompt is good to use.

Comment: In fabric2:
`invocations.console.confirm("do you really want to do this?")` http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#contrib (`invocations` is a standalone package now)

Answer (score 1):

Those both methods are valid and works.

I choose the first one, because I didn't want to have any interaction with my deployment system.

So here is the solution I used:

`% yes | ./manage.py rebuild_index`

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] 
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 27 Items.

Answer (score 1):

The development version of Fabric (1.0a) now supports interaction with remote programs.
http://docs.fabfile.org/1.0a/usage/interactivity.html

Comment: Fabric is now at 1.0.1 and the url is http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/usage/interactivity.html

Comment: Fabric is now at 1.5 and the url is http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/interactivity.html. The documentation has not changed significantly.

Comment: This is fun.  Ok, here's for 1.10: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/interactivity.html.  Next update shouldn't come any earlier than 2017, and then hopefully for Fabric 2!

Comment: 1.13 is here [docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/interactivity.html](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/interactivity.html). For you guys said that in 2011, 2013, 2015... I should add one...It's 2017 now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but hope this would help peoples having similar problem.

***Different point:***

1. Answer ***two or more different input*** to console.
2. [***parallel mode***](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/parallel.html) Support.
3. Any type of input `yes/no/y/n` included.

***Problem***

```
[hostxxx] out: Type 'c' if you want to use the Commercial Edition.
[hostxxx] out: Type 'o' if you want to use the Open Source Edition.
[hostxxx] out: Type '3' to view the GNU General Public License version 3.
[hostxxx] out: Type 'L' to view the Lesser GNU General Public License version 2.1.
[hostxxx] out: Type 'yes' to accept this license offer.
[hostxxx] out: Type 'no' to decline this license offer.
```

***Solution:***

Use `printf` instead of `yes` to add more flexibility, meanwhile this works like a charm on `parallel` mode.

```
@parallel
def demo_multi_input():
    run('printf "o\nyes\n"|./configure --prefix=/home/work/bin/qt')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
run("echo yes|./manage.py rebuild_index")
```